# Where do I change my PHP version for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

My web host is running a different PHP then the one Laravel is using. To overcome this I want Laravel to use another version of PHP. I'm having trouble finding where to do this. My question is it possible and if so where can I change it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it needs to be directed at the webhost's support team.

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is holy, close voters, **do not vote to move this to ServerFault**. It's not appropriate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#server-requirements) has a version of php as a dependancy.  You cannot use a version of Laravel that requires, for example, `PHP>=5.4` on a server that is using a version of PHP below 5.4.

If you have to use an older version of PHP, you need to use an older version of Laravel that supports your desired version of PHP.

Try searching the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) website for older versions, or consider upgrading your version of PHP to match Laravel's requirements.

Comment: Oke tanks, I taught it would be something like this but I wasn't sure ill bee making some changes then.

Answer (score 0):

If your web host is not running a version of PHP that supports Laravel (5.4+), they are a dangerous and unprofessional webhost and you should find a new one. PHP 5.3 and lower have been end-of-lifed (http://php.net/eol.php), meaning they may (and likely do) contain unpatched security holes and other bugs that will never be fixed.

Comment: Yea I know but well I paid for it so I might as well sit out the term and use it for projects that are not that important. Tanks anyway ;).

Comment: I'd demand a refund from a web host that's running 5.3. It's negligent on their part.